# Foreign key constraint has no effect in one to one relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables `test1` and `test2` which have some properties shared so I create a new table `properties` which contain the shared properties.

The problem is that the delete cascading doesn't work because when i delete record from `properties` it still exist in `test1` or `test2` and vice-versa and It seem that the foreign key constraint has no effect at all.

TABLE `test1`

```
CREATE TABLE `test1` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `properties` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  ....
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `..` (`properties`),
  CONSTRAINT `..` FOREIGN KEY (`properties`) REFERENCES `properties` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

TABLE `test2`

```
CREATE TABLE `test2` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `properties` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  .....
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `..` (`properties`),
  CONSTRAINT `..` FOREIGN KEY (`properties`) REFERENCES `properties` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

TABLE `PROPERTIES`

```
CREATE TABLE `properties` (
  `ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test1` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `test2` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  ....

  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `..` (`ao`),
  KEY `..` (`enchere`),
  CONSTRAINT `..` FOREIGN KEY (`test1`) REFERENCES `test1` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `..` FOREIGN KEY (`test2`) REFERENCES `test2` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: How do you even manage to add information without `SET FOREIGN KEY CHECK = 0`?

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu I think `DEFAULT NULL` makes it possible, because null values bypass FK checks.

Comment: So if you delete all the shared properties, you want to delete both original elements as well?

Comment: @Barmar yes that what i want

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu i have `SET FOREIGN KEY CHECK = 1` and i get no error when i insert new record from `test1` and `test2`

Comment: You have got circular references, cascaded deletes will not work in this scenario for violating foreign key constraints.

Comment: @Shadow so what is the solution ?

Comment: I'd say the solution is to keep one-to-one relationship simpler. Only table `properties` should have Foreign Key columns to reference the two other tables. Like you said, you want a one-to-one relationship, so that means `test1` table won't have the same `properties` on multiple records. Nor `test2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- drop schema tomfoolery;
create schema tomfoolery; -- create and use this db/schema so as not to pollute your world
use tomfoolery;
CREATE TABLE `test1` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `properties` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY (`properties`)
  -- CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`properties`) REFERENCES `properties` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `test2` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `properties` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY (`properties`)
  -- CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`properties`) REFERENCES `properties` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `properties` (
  `ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test1` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `test2` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
  -- CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`test1`) REFERENCES `test1` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  -- CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`test2`) REFERENCES `test2` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

alter table test1 add constraint FOREIGN KEY (`properties`) REFERENCES `properties` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
alter table test2 add constraint FOREIGN KEY (`properties`) REFERENCES `properties` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
alter table properties add CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`test1`) REFERENCES `test1` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
alter table properties add CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`test2`) REFERENCES `test2` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

without the above, at least I couldn't get your schema set up right. I guess I could have just turn off FK checking before the create. See schema below with:

```
show create table test1;
show create table test2;
show create table properties;
```

-- schema seems right, now

Due to the circular nature, turning on and off FK checks seems the only way to sustain life in this setup

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1; -- circular so don't check. Note that the below nulls work with check off, but won't work below with not null, so we are doing this here
insert test1(properties) values (null); -- ok
insert test2(properties) values (null); -- ok
insert properties(test1,test2) values (null,null); -- ok

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; -- circular so don't check. Note above works with null but won't work below so we are doing this here
-- again, without the above SET, the following will fail with error 1452
insert test1(properties) values (2); -- ok
insert test2(properties) values (2); -- ok
insert properties(test1,test2) values (2,2); -- ok

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1; -- must turn this back on else cascades will not work
select * from test1;
select * from test2;
select * from properties;
-- note that all 3 tables above have 2 rows with id's 1 and 2

-- now see the cascade deletes will magically work (that is test1 and test2 will have id2 deleted too after the below command)
delete from properties where id=2; -- 1 row affected
use tomfoolery; -- sometimes without doing this, a weird error occurs below saying Error: Error formatting SQL query: empty string given as argument for ! character

select * from test1;
select * from test2;
select * from properties;
```

Cascade delete succeeds on test1,test2

A general Manual Page on [Foreign Key Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) to get one started.

As they are one-to-one, many would say just put the stuff in the native tables anyway, as mentioned by the OP. But it seemed like a challenge, so there it is.

Comment: What's the point of having fk constraints, if the only way to make the structure work is to disable them? Plus you should try what happens if you attempt to delete a record from test1 or test2 that has corresponding records in both the properties and the other test table.

Comment: I had put in enough time at that point having to continuously drop schema and retry about 7 times because the pk ids had to be exact

Comment: it may be lost on the casual observer, but getting to that state above is not trivial. Every attempt to do an insert that fails with Error 1452 also increments the PK value though the slot is not used, thus a gap. Such as 1,3,4,5,6. So 2 never arrives. Then on the other side, since 2 never arrives in another table, you constantly have to examine all the tables to determine if it is possible, or not. Or is a user error or bizarre gap anomaly has occurred.

Comment: I certainly would never use this idiotic approach. But sometimes one wants to learn a little bit, versus trying to present something that anyone would use